# Make style affect whole row

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my word game, when the correct letters spell the word, it will disappear with "wordglow2". At the moment it does this to the word. If I wanted to make the whole row disappear when a correct word was spelt on it, how would I do that?

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
            guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
        }
    }
```

I would have though it would have been like this, but it didn't work...

```
  if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + 'td' + ']').addClass("wordglow2");
```

Comment: change .wordglow to `.wordglow2 td { background: ... }` and then add `.parent()` before you call `addClass('wordglow`)`.

Comment: But .wordglow is already in place for wrong answers @Gavin

Comment: Apologies, my point being, you need to change each of your .wordglow classes so they have ` td` after. Then you apply the class to the parent TR and then it will apply to the whole row instead of the single cell.

Comment: Do you mean change .wordglow2 to .wordglow2 tr and then .parent().addClass('wordglow2') in the script? @Gavin

Comment: Nope, close, `.wordglow2` to `.wordglow2 td` and then using `.parent().addClass('wordglow2');` will add .wordglow2 to the TR of the dragged TD.

Comment: I'll add my suggestion as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

Currently you will have

```
.wordglow2 { background: red; }
```

Update it so it reads

```
.wordglow2 td { background: red; }
```

and then update your jQuery code, so it does

```
$('td[data-word=' + word + ']').parent().addClass("wordglow2");
```

This will then apply the background colour to all of the cells within your row.